# how to foreach array in array in javascript to table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, codeigniter, foreach

i'm trying to foreach a punch of data to my table .. and the data comes from my controller (CI3) i try json encode like this:

```
{"1":{"2":["SOP","SOP 16","YES"]},"3":{"7":["SIP","SIP 12","YES"]},"4":{"18":["SAP","SAP 12","YES"]}}
```

and this is how i try to do foreach in my Javascript :

```
 const table_show = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    document.getElementById('mabody').innerHTML = '';

    let str_table = '';
    data.forEach((ir_labs_1,key_ir_1) =>{
        str_table += '<tr id="data_ir_'+key_ir_1+'"><td>POSM</td><td>' + ir_labs_1 + '</td><td id="osa_'+key_ir_1+'">0</td></tr>';

    })
    document.getElementById('mabody').innerHTML = str_table;

}
```

but i got this kind of error directly when i run it :

```
TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
```

and im not sure what is wrong in my code and i dont know how to fix it .

so can anyone tell me how to fix this one ?

Comment: `data` is an object, not an array. You could iterate over `data.values()` or `data.entries()`.

Comment: hi jabaa thank's for your answer, can you give a example for the data.values or data entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs.

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='mabody'></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    const data = {"1":{"2":["SOP","SOP 16","YES"]},"3":{"7":["SIP","SIP 12","YES"]},"4":{"18":["SAP","SAP 12","YES"]}}

    const table_show = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    document.getElementById('mabody').innerHTML = '';

    let str_table = '';
 
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
         console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
         str_table += '<tr id="data_ir_'+key+'"><td>POSM</td><td>' + JSON.stringify(value, null, 2) + '</td><td id="osa_'+key+'">0</td></tr>';
    }

    document.getElementById('mabody').innerHTML = `<table>${str_table}</table>`;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        console.log('page is  loaded');
        table_show(data)
    });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi manuel thanks for your answer, i try you suggestion but the value is [object object] example `1: [object Object]` and 18 : is the data what i want, can you suggest other method thanks

Comment: I updated my previous answer with a full example working code

Comment: thanks manuel  i try you suggestion and its work , thanks bro